# VB.NET ASP.NET Retrieve a list of conutries form database

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am new to ASP.NET and can't seem to find an answer for my problem.

I want to retrieve a list of countries form a table in my database.

I have found a way to do it in C# but i need to do it in Viusal Basic.

```
private List<Country> PopulateCountry()
{
    using (MyDatabaseEntities dc = new MyDatabaseEntities())
    {
        return dc.Countries.OrderBy(a => a.CountryName).ToList();
    }
}
```

This is the code sample from C# which I tried to convert to VB.net, but I keep getting this error message and can't figure out why.

```
Private Function GetListOfCountries() As List(Of Country)
    Using dc As New MyDatabaseEntities
        Try
            Dim countryList = (From p In dc.Counties Order By p.CountryName
                               Ascending
                               Select p)
            Return countryList.ToList()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Using

End Function
```

On the `Return countryList.ToList()` line i get this error

```
Value of type 'List(Of Country)' cannot be converted to 'List(Of Country)'.
```

[image: Error picture]

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: You have a typo, check your picture - `List(Of County)` vs `List(Of Country)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this function will suit your needs. (your conversion failed due to `County` instead of `Country`, where `County` happens to be a valid entity type as well.)

```
Private Function GetListOfCountries() As List(Of Country)
    Using dc As New MyDatabaseEntities
        Try
            Return dc.Countries.OrderBy(Function(a) a.CountryName).ToList()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return Nothing
        End Try
    End Using

End Function
```

Comment: Yes the typo caused all my problems, and it started from when I created the database and the model. Thanks Malcor and Lajos for pointing it out.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Function GetListOfCountries() As List(Of Country)
Using dc As New MyDatabaseEntities
    Try
        Dim countryList = (From p In dc.Countries Order By p.CountryName
                           Ascending
                           Select p)
        Return countryList.ToList()
    Catch ex As Exception
        Return Nothing
    End Try
End Using
```

End Function

You are selected Counties instead of Countries in your from statement.